# ¿tengo un problema al usar el sysout en java?

Tags: java, spring

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio del libro de `Spring` y cada vez que que hay un ejercicio y manda a imprimir me imprime la instancia del objeto y según el libro debería imprimir otra cosa y estoy copiando el código tal cual en el libro, también comprare con el `github` del libro a ver si estaba mal escrito en el libro pero esta igual, el ejercicio es el siguiente:

Están explicando sobre "*Understanding Bean Instantiation Mode*"

```
package com.apress.prospring5.ch3;

public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    static {
        instance = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

El archivo XML

```
<!-- app-context-xml.xml -->
<beans ...>
<bean id="nonSingleton" class="com.apress.prospring5.ch3.annotated.Singer"
scope="prototype" c:_0="John Mayer"/>
</beans>
```

La clase con que proporciona el `bean` con el

```
\\Singer.java
package com.apress.prospring5.ch3.annotated;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("nonSingleton")
@Scope("prototype")
public class Singer {
    private String name = "unknown";

    public Singer(@Value("John Mayer") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Se supone que esta debería ser la salida y me da las dos primeras lineas pero las dos ultimas donde dice John Mayer imprime la instancia del objeto y no entiendo

> Identity Equal?: false
>
> Value Equal:? false
>
> John Mayer
>
> John Mayer

LA clase con el método `main` donde manda a imprimir los objetos `singer1` y `singer2` según el libro

```
import com.apress.prospring5.ch3.annotated.Singer;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;
public class NonSingletonDemo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx =
        new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:spring/app-context-xml.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        Singer singer1 = ctx.getBean("nonSingleton", Singer.class);
        Singer singer2 = ctx.getBean("nonSingleton", Singer.class);

        System.out.println("Identity Equal?: " + (singer1 ==singer2));
        System.out.println("Value Equal:? " + singer1.equals(singer2));
        System.out.println(singer1);
        System.out.println(singer2);

        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Pero mi salida al final siempre es

> Identity Equal?: false
>
> Value Equal:? false
>
> com.understanding.bean.instantiation.mode.Singer@7a765367
>
> com.understanding.bean.instantiation.mode.Singer@76b0bfab

Answer (score 2):

Hola @JavierMarín lo que tienes que saber es que en Java cuando realizas el `System.out.println(singer1);` java invocara el método `toString` de la clase `Singer` que es heredado a su vez de la clase `Object`(como todo objeto de java),  este método por defecto imprime la referencia del objeto siempre y cuando el objeto no sea `null`, bastara con sobre escribir este método en la clase Singer agregando la siguiente línea de código al final de tu clase:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Singer [name=" + name + "]";
    }
```

En este método defines lo que mostrara el objeto al ser impreso a String, como es una acción muy utilizada los IDEs siempre tienen una opción de auto generado, en eclipse los pasos estando en la clase son: `clic derecho -> source -> Generate toString()` y seleccionas las propiedades a imprimir.

Como estas con un libro si esta clase la conviertes en una entidad de Jpa ten cuidado de no incluir los Objetos Relacionados en el toString (los anotados con one-to-many, many-to-one, one-to-one, etc.) porque generan una impresión cíclica infinita y hacen fallar el programa.